# Retire Vs Retirement

Tags: word-choice, verbs, nouns, infinitives

I am confused between the two:

> My father is due to **retire/retirement** in a few months and is restless.

According to my understanding, *retire* sounds more appropriate. But I am not sure. Could anyone explain the correct form.

Comment: _Retire_ is indeed correct. _Retirement_ is a noun. An alternate way to express this (and use the word "retirement") would be: _My father's retirement will be in a few months; he is becoming restless._  Yet another alternate way to change the tense of the verb "retire": _My father is restless, he is retiring in a few months._

Comment: Question is incomplete. Please edit to show your research effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common usage is:

> My father is due **to** retire...

However, it is not incorrect to use:

> My father is due **for** retirement...